# Bounding $\|fg\|_2$ in terms of $\|f\|_2$ and $\|g\|_2$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, inequality, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $f,g\in L^2[0,1]$. I'm wondering if there's any bounds on $\|fg\|_2$ in terms of $\|f\|_2$ and $\|g\|_2$.  So kind of like a Holder's inequality but not quite. If it helps the space is $L^2[0,1]$ so maybe the fact that $[0,1]$ has finite measure makes things nicer.

I know there are bounds with $\|f\|_4$ and $\|g\|_4$ but I'm specifically looking to stay in $L^2$ here.

Edit: let me add some background

I'm trying to show local existence for the following SPDE:

Let's say we have $x\in [0,1]$ and we have the heat equation

$$\frac{d}{dt}u(x,t) = \Delta u(x,t) + u^3$$ with $u(0,t) = u(1,t) = 0$ and $u(x,0)\in L^2$. I want to show local existence of the weak solution in $L^2$.

Here's what I did:
$$u(x,t) = S(t)u_0 + \int_0^t S(t-s)u^3ds$$

is the weak solution where $S(t)$ is the heat semigroup $(u_0 = u(x,0))$.

Define $$\mathcal{K}(v):= S(t)v_0 + \int_0^t S(t-s)v^3ds$$

Then for $v, w\in L^2$ with $v_0 = w_0$ we consider

\begin{align}
\sup_{t\in [0,T]}\left\| \mathcal{K}v - \mathcal{K}w \right\|_2 &= \sup_{t\in [0,T]}\left\|\int_0^T S(t-s)[v^3-w^3]\,ds\right\|_2\\
&\leq \sup_{t\in [0,T]}\int_0^T\left\|S(t-s)[v^3-w^3]\right\|_2\,ds\\
&\leq \sup_{t\in [0,T]}\int_0^T e^{-\omega_1(t-s)}C\left\|v^3-w^3\right\|_2 \,ds
\end{align}

Now I would like to use the fact that $v^3 -w^3$ factors so that I can bound $\left\|v^3-w^3\right\|_2 \leq M\|v-w\|_2 $ to use a contraction mapping of some sort.  So I'm wondering if there's an inequality that will allow me to say this.  Otherwise I might have to just look at the $L^1\to L^2$ norm of the heat semigroup and use Holder.

Comment: $fg$ need not even belong to $L^{2}$ Eg. On $(0,1)$, $f(x)=g(x)=x^{-1/4}$.

Comment: without extra conditions? Can you give an explicit type of bound you are looking for? Eg bilinear in f and g?

Comment: @CalvinKhor I was trying to avoid going into the background because it's a lot to type but hopefully this helps.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy you can assume that they're in $L^2$.  I added some background for why I'm asking this question.

Comment: A slight modificationof my example shows that such an inequality cannot hold even under the assumption that $fg \in L^{2}$.

Comment: What's the modification you had in mind?

Comment: Hypercontractivity of the Dirichlet Heat Kernel is probably what you need.

Comment: @KesavKrishnan ok I'm not familiar with hypercontractivity of the heat kernel.  Do you have a reference you would suggest? I did a search on it but I'm not sure if what I found is what you were referring to

Comment: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.211.1211&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: The introduction in the reference should help. Heuristically, because of the smoothing effect of the heat kernel (gets rid of all point singularities), you can bound $\|S_{t}u\|_{p}$ in terms of $\|u\|_{2}$ for $p\geq 2$ and $t>0$